# one time activity using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, passwords, authorize

I understand how to create a one time activity that saves to preferences to make the activity appear only once. But can someone show me how to save the "first open" screen to sqlite. I want to prevent users from clearing the data and seeing the screen again.

to clarify

I am looking at a password login tutorial and i want the users to register a password with the app but once the password is set, I want the registration screen removed for security purposes. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLite as your storage is not going to help.

Android will store your database under `/data/data/your.package.name/databases/yourfilename` and thus, when a user clears the data for an app, it will remove any databases, along with shared preferences too.